# Input abc.png of type: <class 'django.core.files.uploadedfile.InMemoryUploadedFile'> is not supported

Tags: python, django

Unable to save image two times in django

Im trying to save image through form in one model and add in another model. But at new_account.save() I get the above error.

```
image_file = request.FILES.get('profile_image')
...
...
instance.save()
                        
new_account = Account.objects.get(id=classroom_profile.user.id)
new_account.profile_image.delete()
new_account.profile_image = image_file
new_account.save()
```

Comment: Have you find a way around?

Comment: @Shedrack , it worked pretty much the same code. Make sure you don't open the image file or store it in a variable before this code. And I don't get image through the form. So when I use form.save() the image is not stored. I use request.FILES['profile_image'] to get the values from the input field. 
<input type="file" onchange="uploadImage(this)" id="upload-image" name="profile_image" accept=".png, .jpg, .jpeg"/>